# karabiner elements json: how to make 'left_option" + "up_arrow" to "up_arrow" x 10?

Tags: karabiner

The title says it all. One more information is that I use apple wired keyboard with macbook pro - "clam shell is closed" while external monitors are attached. I added the following at the correct file, but doesn't work. I want to use it for Xcode and Visual Studio Code, etc.

```
{
                        "description": "Move Up / Down 10",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "up_arrow"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things, first you forgot to add `"type": "basic"`
Second: you must add `"modifiers": {"mandatory": ["left_option"]}`

`{
    "description": "Move Up / Down 10",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {"mandatory": ["left_option"]}
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Thanks! It works fine now! Since I have other 'complex_modifications', I though I may omit 'basic', but it was not.

Comment: @BrianHong I'm glad that it helps. If this solved your problem, then you can approve the answer.

Comment: I just did. Thanks. I also added down_arrow in the same way, and it works great, too!

Answer (score 3):

In addition, if you want to make 'shift + option + up/down' jump 10 lines WITH SELECTION, use this. This also contains another useful modifications for 'cmd + up/down/left/right' to page up/down, home, end with selections:

```
{
    "description": "LCMD + Up to Page Up",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "page_up"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command",
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "page_up",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "description": "LCMD + Down to Page Down",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "down_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "page_down"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "down_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command",
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "page_down",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "description": "LCMD + Left to Home",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "home"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command",
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "home",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "description": "LCMD + Right to End",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "right_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "end"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "basic",
            "from": {
                "key_code": "right_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_command",
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "end",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "description": "Move Up / Down 10",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_option"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_option",
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "up_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "down_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_option"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "down_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "left_option",
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "down_arrow",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "left_shift"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```